# C++: Why is a non-static class method able to be called without a class instance?

Tags: c++

It's been a while since I have written any C++, so when looking up some basic examples to get me started, I was surprised to see something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class TestClass {
public:
    void testMethod(){
        std::cout << "Hello!";
    }    
};

int main()
{
  TestClass test;     // Not being instantiated
  test.testMethod();  // Method still able to be called successfully!
}
```

How is it possible that a non-static method of a class can be called without an instance of the class being created first?

Working example: http://cpp.sh/3wdhg

Comment: Change comment "// Not being instantiated" to "// Instance created"

Comment: So simply declaring the variable with a type creates an instance?

Comment: There it does. Add a constructor and get that to put out a message.  "resource acquisition is initialization"

Comment: I've seen several cases (including my first IRL C++ course!) where the instructor used the word "instantiation" when they actually meant "initialization". Maybe that is the source of the confusion here.

Comment: "instantiation" means to create an instance of the object, "initialization" refers to the setting of initial values for the object

Comment: *Not a dumb question for a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, it actually **is** being instantiated. `test` is an instance of `TestClass`. Thus, `test.testMethod()` is calling a non-static method on an instance of the class.

Comment: Very interesting, not what I expected. Is there a name for this behavior?

Comment: What did you expect? I don't understand why it wouldn't be an instance of the class.

Comment: I expected to be required to call the constructor directly: `TestClass test = TestClass();`

Comment: You're confusing C++ with Java. In Java, `test` is not an instance of `TestClass` but rather a *reference* to an instance of `TestClass`. But in C++, `test` is an instance directly. C++ has different syntax for references. That's just how the languages work.

Comment: @FoxMulder900 you can never "call the constructor" in C++.  Instead, you write code which specifies creation of an object, and part of the process of the object creation involves a constructor call (sometimes).   `TestClass test;` specifies creation of an object .  So does `TestClass test = TestClass();`, the two codes are similar but differ in how the object is initialized (e.g. the latter would set member integer variables to `0` if you had them, and the former won't)

Comment: Thanks RaymondChen and M.M I understand now! I was indeed thinking about things through a Java lens. I'm remembering now that objects in C++ cannot be null, only references can. I would word this question better if I was to ask it again, I was unaware that default constructors would be called automatically upon declaring the variable.

Comment: @Fox [The truth is out there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) I strongly recommend you take advantage of the link and pick out a good book. C++ is very different from other modern languages. Coming in from C and Java the way I did I figured I knew enough to just pick it up. I was wrong. I rewrote a LOT of code after investing in a few good books. Even after you have unlearned all of the C and Java-isms, C++ is probably the most complicated language in wide use today and online tutorials are grossly insufficient. You need quality references.

Comment: Side note: Since you're coming in from Java, the next major mind<expletive deleted>s will likely be [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) and [The Rules of Three ,Five, and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @Fox got you. Yeah, in C++, merely declaring an object of that type creates an instance of the object.

Answer (score 2):

`TestClass test;` is syntax for declaring a variable of type `TestClass`. The variable is an instance of the type. In this case it is an instance of `TestClass`.

> Why is a non-static class method able to be called ...

Because you've created an instance.

> ... without an instance of the class being created first?

Your premise is false.